# Can we use present simple to make another future point for future perfect continuous?

Tags: present-simple, future-perfect, future

Is this sentence correct?

I will have been teaching for 20 years by the time l become 40.

Can I use present simple to make another future point for future perfect continuous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I*** think OP's...

> 1: *I **will have been teaching** for 20 years by then*
> ...is pointlessly complex compared to...
> 2: *I **will have taught** for 20 years by then*

...so I was a bit surprised to see that #1 above puts up a respectable showing on [this usage chart...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=will%20have%20worked%20for%2Cwill%20have%20been%20working%20for%2CI%20will%20have%20worked%2CI%20will%20have%20been%20working&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20)

[image]

Note that NGrams has a 5-word limit on search strings, so I did two versions of each tense - one with initial subject ***I***, the other with trailing preposition ***for*** - to help focus on the usage in question.

It's interesting to note that when I "drilled down" to look at some *actual* written instances in context, *every single one* of the first page of 10 matches for #1 above was from a *text intended to teach or test English.* Only *one* of the first 10 instances of #2 was such a "TEFL" text - and it was on the exact same page as appeared among the #1 results anyway! (So it was only really "guilty by association"! :)

In short, this "past continuous in the future" usage is apparently far more popular with people who teach English for a living than people who actually *speak* English!

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/126/fumblefingers thank you so much, it was so helpful 